# Quadratic Equation roots when there is a constant

Tags: roots, quadratics

What are the roots of x2+x-2n where n is a constant?
Can someone help me with a step by step approach?

Comment: You have asked several questions here. All of them show no effort to solve them. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}0=x^2+x-2n&=x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}-\left(2n+\frac{1}{4}\right)\\&=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(2n+\frac{1}{4}\right)\end{align}$$

Therefore, the equation is equivalent to $$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=2n+\frac{1}{4}$$

From where $$x=\pm\sqrt{2n+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @mfl No, the solution is what I wrote. The equation above is the one that had a typo.

Comment: How did you get 1/4 and -(2n+1/4) as roots

Comment: @Karan The roots are $\sqrt{2n+1/4}-1/2$ and $-\sqrt{2n+1/4}-1/2$, not $1/4$ and $-(2n+1/4)$.

Comment: What i intend to ask is the method to arrive at the roots.